# resize window.print() screen in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using `onclick="window.print()"` on button print. Now the print screen overlaps the current screen. So I need to reduce the size of the print screen. I cannot use JQuery as there is no specific #id, the whole page has to be printed.

Comment: You cannot control the appearance of the native browser "print" dialog.

Comment: the print dialog is something the browser generates, or invokes a standard system window. It is NOT possible to control how/where that dialog appears.

Comment: @Pointy ,@Marc  could we transfer the entire html page to another window for print with only print option.

Comment: You cannot prevent the browser from presenting the user with the "print" dialog. Consider that some (many) users have several different printing options available, and your client code has no way to know that or control it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't crop printing area, but you can define a CSS style different for printing.

https://www.arclab.com/en/webformbuilder/how-to-print-a-specific-part-of-a-html-page-css-media-screen-print.html